# How to find french UTF-8 accent character in R with the simple character using str_detect?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I need to find accented characters with the simple character. For example: "é","è" or "ê" with e in French Canadian, UTF-8.

```
 library(tidyverse)

 Sys.setlocale(locale = "fr_CA.UTF-8")
 a <- c("Léger", "leger")

 str_detect(a, regex("leger", ignore_case=T))
 ## [1]  FALSE  TRUE

 str_detect(a, coll("leger", ignore_case=T, locale = "fra"))
 ## [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

The results of this code should be TRUE, TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the input string to just use ASCII characters then do the match on that. For example

```
str_detect(iconv(a, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT'),regex("leger", ignore_case=T))
# [1] TRUE TRUE
```